# lxml length of web parsed content

Tags: python, lxml, scrape

I scrape web pages with `lxml` in Python. Yet, to get the number of table rows I first get them all and then use `len()` function. I feel it's wasteful, is there other way to get their number (dynamic one) for further scraping?

```
import lxml.html
doc = ''
try:
    doc = lxml.html.parse('url')
except SkipException: pass 

if doc: 
    buf = ''
    #get the total number of rows in table
    tr = doc.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr")
    table = []
    # iterate over the table rows limited to max number
    for i in range(3, len(tr)):
            # get the rows content                                              
            table += doc.xpath("body/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[%s]/td" % i)
```

Comment: Why the `beautifulsoup` tag? You are using `lxml` here only.

Comment: sorry, i thought one may use bs instead for improoving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `tr` elements you matched as the starting point, you can simply iterate over them like you would with a python list:

```
tr = doc.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr")
for row in tr[3:]:
    table += row.findall('td')
```

The above uses `.findall()` to grab all contained `td` elements, but you could use further `.xpath()` calls if you need more control.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import islice

trs = doc.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr")
for tr in islice(trs, 3):
   for td in tr.xpath('td'):
      ...whatever...
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use an iterator approach, as explained in this section: http://lxml.de/api.html#iteration ? I am pretty sure that there is such a way. Finding the length of something and then iterating over it with (x)range afterwards never is an elegant solution and I am pretty sure that the guys behind lxml provide you with the right tools.